# How to call a function of a class from another file in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

This is my initial screen:

**LoginScreen.js**

```
import { Toast } from 'native-base'

class LoginScreen extends Component {

  showError(error) {
    Toast.show({
      text: error
    })
  }

.....

}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(LoginScreen)
```

I am trying to invoke the `showError` function below like this:

**loginAction.js**

```
import LoginScreen from './LoginScreen'

let a = LoginScreen.showError('Testing')
```

I am getting an error saying:

```
LoginScreen.showError() is not a function
```

Comment: Convert `showError` to a `static` function if it doesn't have any reference to the current object.

Comment: It had a reference so `static` was not the way to go. Anyway, thanks for commenting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `showError` isn't related to `LoginScreen` and doesn't use its instance, it shouldn't be its method. The use of classes as namespaces is antipattern in modern JavaScript, ES modules serve this purpose:

```
export function showError(error) {
  Toast.show({
    text: error
  })
}

class LoginScreen extends Component {...}
```

Since `showError` doesn't do anything that would be specific to login screen and may be reused in other places, it could be moved from `LoginScreen` to common module.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Sorry, I was a little busy that's why couldn't reply to your post.

Answer (score 2):

You can statically define the method you want to call in another file.
In your case :

```
import { Toast } from 'native-base'

class LoginScreen extends Component {

  static showError(error) {
    Toast.show({
      text: error
    })
  }

.....

}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(LoginScreen)
```

And then just call it like :

```
import LoginScreen from './LoginScreen'

let a = LoginScreen.showError('Testing')
```